# Unable to browse published npm packages on Nexus

Tags: npm, nexus

NPM publishes to Nexus under the dash "-" folder. Packages cannot be viewed using Browse Storage.

1. How to avoid the dash "-" folder?
2. Is there way to publish npm packages with the folder structure like NuGet?
3. Is it possible to have a structure like this?

   ```
   PRIVATE_NPM/
   |
   |--package-1.0.0/
   |  |
   |  |--package-1.0.0.tgz
   |
   |--package-1.0.1/
      |
      |--package-1.0.1.tgz
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The repository structure in Nexus is standard, and the "-" is part of that standard, it's used to retrieve metadata.

There is a [declined feature request](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-7570) (Nexus 2.10) for an NPM package browsing UI.